# How to correctly pass State to a different function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have tried writing a simple rock, paper, scissors application using react. Now I am fully stuck at getting the pick in the dynamically painted radiobutton back to the main App.

I have tried countless things to get this working -> Below you can find the last piece of code tried. What would I have to do to acutally get this working ?

Thanks!

```js
const Plays = (props) => {

  return (
    props.options.map(option =>
      <label key={option.name}>
        <input
          disabled={isEnemy(props.playerName)}
          key={props.playerName + option.name}
          className="gameItem"
          type="radio"
          onChange={(event) => {
            return props.setPlayerPick(option.name);
          }}
          value={props.playerName + option.name}
        />
        <img className="crop" src={option.img} alt="" />
      </label>)
  );
}

const App = () => {

  const [playerPick, setPlayerPick] = useState('')

  const options = [
    { name: 'rock', img: rock },
    { name: 'paper', img: paper },
    { name: 'scisscors', img: scissors }
  ]

  const playerName = ['Enemy', 'Player'];

  const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(playerPick);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="description">
        This is a simple ( Rock | Paper | Sciscors ) game against a computer!
      </div>
      <div className="body">
        <div className="playerName">Enemy</div>
        <Plays options={options} playerName={playerName[0]} />
        <div className="playerName">You</div>
        <Plays handleChoosing={setPlayerPick()} options={options} playerName={playerName[1]} />
        <button onClick={handleOnSubmit} className="goButton">Go!</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

This is the error I now get, so I feel like I successfully got the state over but it does render to often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleChoosing={setPlayerPick()}` will, on every render, cause to render the component again, causing the infinite loop. You may just want to pass the function, instead of invoking it. Probably something like:

```
<Plays setPlayerPick={setPlayerPick} options={options} playerName={playerName[1]} />
```

Comment: Thanks! -> This does lead me in the other direction of the issue though. 
The Infinite loop would be solved like this, now the problem is that I can not pass back the option.name property. If I keep the line `onChange={(event) => {
            return props.setPlayerPick(option.name);
          }}`, I get the error : **props.setPlayerPick is not a function.**

.
Edit: Ah got it have to call handleChoosing now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting the error due to the function passed to handleChoosing. Try and change it to 
handleChoosing={() => setPlayerPick ()}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this,

```
handleChoosing={setPlayerPick()}
```

You are immediately calling the function on component load, so it taking you to infinite loop. You need to write only `setPlayerPick` like,

```
handleChoosing={setPlayerPick}
```

Also in `Play` component, you don't need to return anything, also from parent component you are passing props `handleChoosing` but in `Play` component you are using `setPlayerPick` which is wrong,

```
onChange={(event) => {return props.setPlayerPick(option.name);}}
```

You just need to do this,

```
onChange={(event) => props.handleChoosing(option.name)}
```